# Bootstrap From with multi line and button on bottom right

Tags: bootstrap-4

I try this but the row contain button is not on the bottom of first container. I find lot of sample with the button on the bottom of the page but is not my case; I want keep a &st container. (I use angular component so my conponent is in other component).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="float-left">
                <span>line 1 left</span>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
               <span>line 1 right</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="float-left">
                <span>line 2 left</span>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
               <span>line 2 right</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="float-right">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Go</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  |
|  |  line 1 left                                                   line 1 right  |  |
|  +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  |
|  |  line 2 left                                                   line 2 right  |  |
|  +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  |
|                                                                                    |
|                                                                                    |
|                                                                                    |
|                                                                                    |
|                                                                                    |
|                                                                                    |
|  +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  |
|  |                                                                    | Go |    |  |
|  +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly many ways to achieve this. The two I can think of are:

1. Flexbox
2. Absolute positioning

I will go over the flexbox approach.

The basic idea of the flexbox approach is that

- Display your form as flexbox with the flow being column
- Set a minimum height on the form so that there are some spaces you can play around with
- Define two sections for the lines and the actions, where you place your submit button
- Finally you set its `justify-content` to `between` so that the lines and actions section are separated

```html
<div class="container">
    <form class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between" style="min-height: 50vh;">
        <section class="lines">
            ...
        </section>
        <section class="actions text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Go</button>
        </section>
    </form>
</div>
```

You can find the documentation of those Bootstrap flex utility classes here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/.

And here is the screenshot:

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/joz70d3r/27/

#### My 2 cents

1. I don't usually nest containers. I tend to have just 1 container (either `.container` or `.container-fluid`) for the structure of 1 section outside and use other elements within it.
2. I don't use `float-*` that much when I have flexboxes to work with. For the lines, I used `.row` along with `.justify-content-between` again to separate the left and right item. I also used [`.col-auto`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#auto-sizing) to make sure the column only takes up the necessary space, not extra.

   ```
   <div class="row justify-content-between">
       <div class="col-auto">
           line 1 left
       </div>
       <div class="col-auto">
           line 1 right
       </div>
   </div>
   ```